# Can't build for iOS after upgrading Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, ios9, facebook-unity-sdk

After upgrading to iOS9 the FB integration has seized to work with my app. To fix this, I updated the Facebook SDK (to version 7.2.2) to be used with Unity 4.6.9, and after the necessary changes the integration works fine in the editor.

But now I can't build the whole app to the device any more, as 
Xcode (version 7.1) It just giving me 19 errors similar to this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_IOSLogInWithReadPermissions", referenced from:
>   _IOSFacebook_IOSLogInWithReadPermissions_m971 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o (maybe you meant:
>   _IOSFacebook_IOSLogInWithReadPermissions_m971)

I've checked in [the Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)
but it seems to me that it only tells me to update the plist file. But when I look at my plist file, it already looks like what is in the documentation.

How can I fix the undefined symbols error with Facebook SDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FacebookSDK for Unity iOS Mach-O linker error - undefined symbols \_iosLogin,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104990/facebooksdk-for-unity-ios-mach-o-linker-error-undefined-symbols-ioslogin)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that starting with Facebook Unity SDK version **7.1.0 (September 21, 2015)** they dropped support for Unity 4, see the [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log) and the first line of the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted) page.

> BREAKING CHANGE: Unity 4 is no longer supported. Unity 5 is required

Anyhow the reason this breaks, that [Unity 5 allows to put plugins somewhere else](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UpgradeGuide5-Plugins.html) than in the Plugins folder, and Facebook Unity SDK uses that feature and put their Objectice-C code into ***Facebook/Editor/iOS***.

You could try to move it into ***Plugins/iOS***. But you might run into more issues....

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I had noticed the Unity 5 requirement (I should have probably mentioned that), but I didn't know about the change regarding the Plugin folder requirement. 

I tried moving the plugin stuff, but unfortunately I'm indeed facing new problems after that. Now I'm getting this error (among others):
 FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found.

I don't know if this is related, but I had to make two changes to the code after moving the plugin stuff: eg. UnityEditor.FacebookEditor was "using FB.Unity.Editor", which I commented out as that didn't seem to be in use.

Comment: Fix to previous comment, by "FB.Unity.Editor" I meant "Facebook.Unity.Editor".